# Suggestions on how to add capacitors to MCP1406

Tags: eaglecad, mosfet-driver, decoupling-capacitor

I'm using a mosfet driver, model [MCP1406](https://docs.rs-online.com/5844/0900766b8137e9ac.pdf) and it works very fine by wiring it as showed in the following picture (I control it  by PE0-2 connect to my microcontroller) and it drives a 2A load (a coil).
[image]

As suggested in the datasheet, I added the capacitors C106, C105 and C104.

Since I need to add multiple MCP1406 to my circuit to drive 10 mosfets, I would like to ask you if I need to add these capacitors near each driver or if I can just put them between GND and +12VDC only one time to save components and space on my PCB.

EDIT:

I changed the value of the ceramic capacitor C104 to 2.5nF to fit the suggestions of the datasheet and @Andy aka.
I would like to change the film capacitor C105 to find a package smaller, but I searched a lot and I could not find anything smaller than the ECWF(A) series with dimensions 18.1 x 8.5 x 13.3mm.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet states this: -

> **These capacitors should be placed close to the driver to minimized
> circuit board parasitics and provide a local source for the required
> current.**

It also says this: -

> **Large currents are required to charge and discharge capacitive loads
> quickly. For example, 2.25A are needed to charge a 2500 pF load with
> 18V in 20 ns.**

So, if you want to play safe, fit the recommended capacitors to all the MCP1406 chips that you use. If you want to take a risk and only fit the ceramic 0.1 μF capacitors close to each chip then you might get away with it but, as with all these types of question, unless the data sheet explicitly states otherwise, you should fit the full compliment of capacitors it recommends.

Comment: thank you for the support! I changed the capacitor value C104 to 2.5nF and the film capacitor C105 to 1.0uF as also reported in the datasheet and I will place them very close to each driver. I reported these changes to my first post. Is it better now? Unfortunately, I would like to find a film capacitor with a smaller footprint than ECWF(A) with 18.1 x 8.5 x 13.3mm, but I was able to find anything. Do you have any ideas for it? I really need to save space in my PCB. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to replace the film capacitor with a ceramic one? The load to control is a 2A coil from an hydraulic valve.